# Docker: Browsersync not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, gulp, browser-sync

I'm encountering an issue with my Node.js app using Gulp, Browsersync and Docker.

When running locally with `gulp watch`, everything works fine.

However, when using `docker-compose up`, I get an error

> Cannot GET /

The Browsersync UI on port 3001 works as expected.

Running app locally:

```
gulp watch
```

[image]

Running in Docker container:

```
docker-compose up
```

I get error:

> Cannot GET /

[image]

Error message in the web browser console:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-ZfFIHrd9MzirQdadZrM3hznhYlx+PRQo8+OCWjaPDaY='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
> 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
> fallback

Docker compose logs: it doesn't produce any error and just logs same output as when I run it locally with `gulp watch`.

```
 docker-compose up

[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                                  docker:desktop-linux
WARN[0000] Found orphan containers ([boilerplate-app-1]) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container boilerplate-node-1  Created                                                                                                                                 0.0s
Attaching to boilerplate-node-1
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:39] Using gulpfile /Users/filiphuhta/Documents/Projects/Bitbucket/boilerplate/gulpfile.js
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:39] Starting 'watch'...
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:39] Starting 'cleanDist'...
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:39] Finished 'cleanDist' after 1.61 ms
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:39] Starting 'buildScripts'...
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:39] Starting 'lintScripts'...
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:39] Starting 'buildStyles'...
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:39] Starting 'copyFiles'...
boilerplate-node-1  | Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
boilerplate-node-1  |   npx update-browserslist-db@latest
boilerplate-node-1  |   Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:40] Finished 'copyFiles' after 413 ms
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:40] Finished 'buildScripts' after 417 ms
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:40] Finished 'lintScripts' after 417 ms
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:40] Finished 'buildStyles' after 419 ms
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:40] Starting 'startServer'...
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:40] Finished 'startServer' after 28 ms
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:40] Starting 'watchSource'...
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:40] Finished 'watchSource' after 1.43 ms
boilerplate-node-1  | [07:52:40] Finished 'watch' after 454 ms
boilerplate-node-1  | [Browsersync] Access URLs:
boilerplate-node-1  |  -----------------------------------
boilerplate-node-1  |        Local: http://localhost:3000
boilerplate-node-1  |     External: http://172.18.0.2:3000
boilerplate-node-1  |  -----------------------------------
boilerplate-node-1  |           UI: http://localhost:3001
boilerplate-node-1  |  UI External: http://localhost:3001
boilerplate-node-1  |  -----------------------------------
boilerplate-node-1  | [Browsersync] Serving files from: assets/
boilerplate-node-1  | [Browsersync] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
```

**gulpfile.js**:

```
let startServer = function (done) {
    if (!settings.reload) return done();

    // Initialize BrowserSync
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: paths.reload,
            directory: true
        },
        proxy: "node:3000",
    });
    done();
};
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY gulpfile*.js ./
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --global gulp-cli
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000 3001

CMD ["gulp watch"]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "1"
services:
  node:
    build: .
    command: gulp watch
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "3001:3001"
```

The browsersync UI works fine on port `3001`:
[image]

I'm not that good at configuring Docker containers, so it could definitely be something that I have missed. What could cause the problem with `Cannot GET /` for the files that should be available on port `3000` when I use the **docker container** instead of **locally** on my machine?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What logs do you see when you start the service (ie what is the output from `docker compose up`)?

Comment: Updated with the error message in the webbrowser console @Phil

Comment: That's not what I asked. When you run `docker compose up`, it should log a bunch of information to the terminal. What does that look like?

Comment: Updated with docker compose logs and it dosen't give any error? If that was what you meant @Phil

Answer (score 0):

Your Docker setup for running a Node.js app with BrowserSync is encountering a "`Cannot GET /`" error.

```bash
Local Machine:
Browser ─> Gulp Watch ─> BrowserSync ─> Node.js App

Docker Container:
Browser ─> Docker ─> Gulp Watch ─> BrowserSync ─> Node.js App
```

The [BrowserSync server](https://browsersync.io/docs) is not serving the files correctly when running in Docker.

---

You might need to change the proxy setting in your BrowserSync configuration. The `node:3000` proxy does not seem correct because Docker might be expecting the service name from the `docker-compose.yml` file. If `node` is the name of your service, this is fine, but make sure the Node.js app is running and accessible on port 3000 within the container.

Make sure your files are correctly copied into the Docker container. You might need to define a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) in your `docker-compose.yml` to make sure the local files are being served:

```yaml
services:
 | node:
 | volumes:
 | - .:/usr/src/app
```

Your Dockerfile only copies `gulpfile.js` and `package.json`. Make sure to copy your entire project directory (or at least the necessary files to run the app) into the Docker container.

```
# Add this line to your Dockerfile
COPY . .
```

But make sure to exclude the `node_modules` directory from being copied into the container. You can do this by adding a `.dockerignore` file to your project directory:

```
node_modules/
npm-debug.log
.git/
.gitignore
.env
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
**/.DS_Store
**/Thumbs.db
```

The error message in the web browser console indicates a [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) issue. If you have a CSP set up, make sure it allows for the necessary scripts to run.

Your `docker-compose.yml` would be:

```yaml
version: "1"
services:
  node:
    build: .
    command: gulp watch
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

And `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm install --global gulp-cli
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000 3001

CMD ["gulp watch"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check BrowserSync Configuration in Docker Container:**

```
let startServer = function (done) {
    if (!settings.reload) return done();

    // Inisialisasi BrowserSync
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: paths.reload,
            directory: true
        },
        proxy: "node:3000",
    });

    console.log("Configuration BrowserSync:", browserSync.config);

    done();
};
```

Add some debug output into your `gulpfile.js` to print the BrowserSync configuration when running in a Docker container. This can help you verify that the configuration is correct and meets your expectations.